# Perl XML::twig : Find a substring located before a child element in mixed content

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I'm working on a XML file with some mixed content (elements containing text, one child tag, then text again).
I would like to extract, for each parent element, the word (substring) coming right before the child element.

### Example of XML Input :

```
<root>
<parent> there is text all <child>text</child> around it</parent>
<parent> there is text all <child>text</child> around it</parent>
<parent> there is text all <child>text</child> around it</parent>
<parent> there is text all <child>text</child> around it</parent>
</root>
```

### Example of Text Output :

```
all
all
all
all
```

I know that applying `text_only` to the `parent` element will give me `there is text all around it`, so I don't have to deal with the child element anymore, but then I don't know how to locate the preceding word.

Should I replace the `child` element by some kind of textual marker like `|` and just go through the remaining text as a single string ?

I'm not asking for a full "ready-made" answer, but some directions would sure be helpful.

Comment: How is that related @toolic? It's not the same definitely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find each `child` element and then check the text of its sibling on the left. That's the *previous sibling*. Conveniently [there is a method `prev_sibling_text`](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig#first_child_text-optional_condition) that gives you just that, since the previous sibling is a text node anyway. From there, it's just a matter of locating the last word.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    TwigHandlers => {
        child => sub {
            say +( split /\s/, $_->prev_sibling_text )[-1];
        },
    }
);

$twig->parse( \*DATA );

__DATA__
<root>
<parent> there is text all <child>text</child> around it</parent>
<parent> there is text all <child>text</child> around it</parent>
<parent> there is text all <child>text</child> around it</parent>
<parent> there is text all <child>text</child> around it</parent>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not realize that text in mixed content could be considered as an element and not as a string !

Comment: Each piece of text is a node. In your case you have `parent node: (text node, child node: (text node), text node)`. Getting all the text inside `parent` is a special function.